# TargetException on add to list

Tags: c#, devexpress

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
   myCollection.Add(measurement);
}));
```

I add a Measurement object to a `ObservableCollection<Measurement>` and get "A first chance exception of type `'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Additional information: `Object does not match target type.`"

I don't understand why this is getting thrown since they both are the same type.
stack trace:

```html
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(object target)    Unknown
    System.dll!System.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object target, object[] args) Unknown
    System.dll!System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(object component)   Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Browsing.RelatedDataBrowser.RetrieveDataSource()  Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowser.DataSource.get() Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowser.Current.get()    Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Browsing.RelatedDataBrowser.RetrieveDataSource()  Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowser.DataSource.get() Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowser.Current.get()    Unknown
    DevExpress.Charts.v14.2.Core.dll!DevExpress.Charts.Native.SeriesBindingProcedure.CreateBindingPoints()  Unknown
    DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.Series.UpdateSeriesBinding(object dataSource) Unknown
    DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.Diagram.UpdateBinding()   Unknown
    DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.ChartControl..ctor.AnonymousMethod__c()   Unknown
    DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.v14.2.dll!DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.Native.BindingBehavior.DataSourceChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)   Unknown
    System.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Data.Measurement>.OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
    System.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.__Canon>.InsertItem(int index, System.__Canon item)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Data.Measurement>.Add(Data.Measurement item) Unknown
>   MyApp.exe!MyApp.Data.ViewModels.CompleteMeasurementsViewModel.MeasurementAddedFromDevice.AnonymousMethod__29() Line 293 C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeDelegateCore()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()  Unknown
    MyApp.exe!App.Main()    C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown
```

crashes on consistency check? The weird part is this doesn't happen alot. Please shed some light on this

EDIT:

If I keep hitting continue I get this exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Additional information: `Property accessor 'Vehicle' on object 'Location' threw the following exception:'Object does not match target type.'`

The scenario in this post seems to be similar to mine... http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/gridview-object-does-not-match-target-type-error-during-binding-collection-of-different-type-objec.121226/

Comment: You did not give enough information to help you. What type is measueremen? show this class. Do you change `measurement` while its accessed by another thread?

Comment: Could a dynamic proxy generated from entity framework cause this issue?

Comment: The TargetInvocationException indicates that some exception occurred, but it provides too few details. I suggest that you set this option on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx. And set this option off: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc%28VS.80%29.aspx. This way, you will be able to stop exactly at the line where the "Property accessor .." exception is raised and analyze the stack trace and local variables.

Comment: Could we see the definition of your observable collection and 'measurement'? Thanks.